# Kendo UI - Minified JS size is 1.8MB

Tags: performance, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

One of my clients report slow loading of their landing page. They use ASP.NET MVC with Kendo UI. I did a quick check and noticed that the kendo.all.min.js is about 1.8MB and client says this is required. I am sure they do not use all of the kendo UI elements in the landing page. I have never used Keno before but only JQuery. Is there a way to minimize the kendo script file size further by not including everything and choose only the elements that are required and form the final JS (like cherry picking in JQuery?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a tool for creating custom downloads at http://www.telerik.com/download/custom-download  with an overview of picking what you need [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/custom)